# How to loop through custom taxonomies and sub taxonomies and display posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

So I have a custom taxonomy of continent which is linked to a custom post type of offices.

Under the continent category I have:

```
Europe
-- Germany
----- The Posts
-- United Kingdom
----- The Posts
Asia
-- Australia
----- The Posts
-- New Zealand
----- The Post
```

Ideally I'd like the HTML to look something like:

```
<h2>Europe</h2>
<h3>Germany</h3>
<ul>
<li>The post</li>
</ul>
```

What's the best way to go about this? I've been struggling to get the sub taxonomy and then get the posts.

Sorry if this question has already been posted, I couldn't find anything but I could be wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use tax_query for this purpose.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'offices',
'tax_query' => array(
    array (
        'taxonomy' => 'europe',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'germany',
    )
),
```

) );

You can also use more then one term in this query.

Comment: Thanks, how could i get this into one big loop to loop through each taxonomy?

Comment: You can use get_taxonomies( ) function to get all taxonomies and loop through this array.